# Is there a way to optimize multiple gifs playing at once in a collection view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm building an iMessage extension where a lot of gifs are playing at once since the emoji that can be sent is animated.  I'm currently using FLAnimatedImage to display gif images.  All my gifs are being displayed in a collection view, and when the user scrolls it causes lots of lag.

Are there any other methods to display lots of gifs at once without causing lag?

I've tried using SwiftGIF, GIFSwift, and built in UIImage animation, but FLAnimatedImage causes the least amount of lag on scroll, but still very noticeable on slower devices.

Comment: When you detect that the user is scrolling, stop animating the gifs.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I'll give that a try now.

Comment: How do you stop animating when the user scrolls?